# how print false if column value is 0 or less than 0 or null,print true if value is greater than 0

Tags: php

i am trying to make a web page that fetch value from database .i fetch 3 column from table councel name councel name ,smscount emailcount,i want if smscount and emailcount value is null or 0 or less than 0 then print false and if value is greater than 0 then print true.
how can i do this task.
code for getting value from table column is

```
     <?php 
      // Connects to your Database 
     mysql_connect("localhost", "root","root") or die(mysql_error()); 
     echo "connec to local host"; 
     mysql_select_db("Court") or die(mysql_error());
     echo "connec to Database"; 
     $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM councel") 
     or die(mysql_error()); 
     Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
     while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
     { 
     Print "<tr>"; 
     Print " <td>".$info['CouncelName'] . "</td> "; 
     Print " <td>".$info['SMSCount'] . "</td> "; 
     Print " <td>".$info['EmailCount'] . " </td></tr>"; 
     } 
     Print "</table>"; 
     ?> 


      ![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: you can't make it into `if else` block of what you have written ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that your values are integers you can just do this way:

```
if($info['EmailCount'] && $info['SMSCount'] && $info['EmailCount'] >= 0 && $info['SMSCount'] >= 0){
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Sir my value is integer value i want if value is 0 or less then 0 print false and if value is greater than 0 means any integer 1,2...542...1000, then print true

Comment: on both values? (EmailCount and CouncelName)

Comment: no sir email count and sms count

Comment: ok, i updated the answer, check my code. It should do the trick :)

Comment: SIR one more question i want to sort my all true value and all false value with combo box.means if user select true from combo box then all table data is sort according true value and if select false data sort acording false value

Comment: you want a combo box with true/false value and on select it shows only the rows where emailcount and smscount are actually true or false?

Comment: Yes sir i want if user select from cobo is true then all true value and correspondence to true value show.and if select false all false value and corespondence to false value show